# Ubuntu 16.04 has no VMWare console access once booted on VMWare vSphere 5.5 Cluster with EFI

Tags: server, grub2, uefi, vmware, 16.04

I installed a fresh Ubuntu Server 16.04 on our VMWare cluster to try it out and begin building a template for it. After install, the IP address is displayed and it seems to work if I SSH into it, but I can't see anything on the console. I tell it to do a guest OS reboot and that works, I see stuff on the screen during the boot process, but then when I expect to be shown the typical text login screen, it goes blank. Trying to interact with it doesn't make anything show up. I checked that open-vm-tools was installed and it is. I did choose the EFI instead of BIOS for the VM which isn't typical for us at this point.

The vmgfx is shown loaded according to lsmod's output.

lshw & lspci show the following information on the display adapter:

```
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter


   *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: SVGA II Adapter
         vendor: VMware
         physical id: f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=vmwgfx latency=64
         resources: irq:16 ioport:1140(size=16) memory:f4000000-f7ffffff memory:f8000000-f87fffff memory:80000000-80007fff
```

I also uncommented the /etc/defaults/grub line "GRUB_TERMINAL=console".

Any suggestions on getting the VMWare console login screen to come up?

Comment: I'm having this problem now. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd instead of upstart.  to configure systemd for serial console, you only need to update grub2 to use the serial console, and systemd will also be configured for serial console.

all you need to do is, modify the lines in the **/etc/default/grub**  file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

then execute `update-grub`

make sure you use **ttyS0** ... it's case-sensitive ... otherwise you'll only see the grub boot menu, and you won't get an actual console

see also:  http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html

Comment: I'm not talking about the serial console. I'm talking about the VMWare console.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have this exact problem but generally issues with the serial console and 16.04. I found this helped, and perhaps it would help your case as well. Remembering that 16.04 introduces systemd, either

```
systemctl start getty@ttyS0.service
```

should help or:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service  /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@ttyS0.service
```

Followed by a reboot. (The latter worked for me.)

Found this at 
https://www.it-hure.de/2012/04/enable-serial-console-with-systemd/

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Thanks for sharing though. It looked promising. :-)

Comment: Aw shoot! Frustrating, for sure.

Comment: Well, I have SSH so it isn't the end of the world, but it isn't going into production any time soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, fixed it by setting the grub screen resolution and then restarting.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

You can also do this once at boot if you can see the grub boot menu by pressing 'e' and changing the setting like so:

```
gfxmode "800x600"
```

then press control+X to boot.